# How to use .htaccess to redirect example.com.tw to example.com?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

## **Summary**

I have bought two domains, both 'example.com.tw' and 'example.com'. I hope that when a user input 'example.com.tw' in the address bar, it can redirect to 'example.com' automatically. Below is my try.

## **My try**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com\.tw [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

## **Questions**

1. Is it correct above?
2. Is there any better way to improve the code above?

The issue is that when a user input the subdomain (Such as: 'news.example.com.tw'), will it redirect correctly? (Will it redirect to 'news.example.com' successfully?)

Comment: no, it's not correct. `http://www.*.com` is not a valid url. rewriterules are `rewriterule pattern target options`. `*` is not a valid dns hostname/domainname.

Comment: `*` is just the representation of my website's name.

Comment: then use `example.com`.

Comment: The `*` (asterisk) has special meaning in a regex, so anyone trying to read your code above will immediately see it as incorrect.

Comment: @w3d: it's a regex metachar, but wasn't being used in the regex portion of the rule/conds.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, but the OP wasn't using it as such initially - just as a placeholder for their domain name (which, for anyone reading the code/regex, wouldn't make sense).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `.tw` TLD:

Assuming both domains point to the same place and any subdomains are simply in subdirectories off the main domains document root (or point to the document root of the main domain itself). Then, in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.tw$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Replace `302` (temporary) with `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.